# NOAA API returning impossible historical temperature values

Tags: python, weather-api, noaa

**API:**

https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2

**Parameters:**

`CITY:US270013` specifies Minneapolis, MN

`datatypeid=TOBS` specifies that I want the observed temperature

**Python Code**

```
url = 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&locationid=CITY:US270013&startdate=2016-05-01&enddate=2016-05-31&limit=1000&datatypeid=TOBS'

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
response = response.json()
stationData = pd.DataFrame(response['results'])
print(stationData.sort_values(by='station').to_string(index=False))
```

**Results:**

```
attributes datatype                 date            station  value
 ,,7,2400     TOBS  2016-05-01T00:00:00  GHCND:USC00211448     89
 ,,7,2400     TOBS  2016-05-14T00:00:00  GHCND:USC00211448      6
 ,,7,2400     TOBS  2016-05-07T00:00:00  GHCND:USC00211448     61
 ,,7,2400     TOBS  2016-05-16T00:00:00  GHCND:USC00211448    106
 ,,7,2400     TOBS  2016-05-26T00:00:00  GHCND:USC00211448    172
 ,,7,2400     TOBS  2016-05-28T00:00:00  GHCND:USC00211448    161
 ,,7,2400     TOBS  2016-05-17T00:00:00  GHCND:USC00211448     50
 ,,7,2400     TOBS  2016-05-06T00:00:00  GHCND:USC00211448    178
```

According to that table, May 6th 2015 had an observed temperature of 178 degrees in Minneapolis. This is clearly wrong but there is little documentation on their website. Does their `TOBS` follow a different scale for temperatures, or is there a different variable I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/readme.txt

```
TOBS = Temperature at the time of observation (tenths of degrees C)
```

Divide your results by 10, multiply by 9/5 + 32 to convert to F (or whatever you need to do).

Minneapolis can be freezing in May!